# What Pokémon from generations already introduced are currently obtainable in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've noticed Pokémon from new generations are introduced in small batches, with more coming after the initial release of a new generation. Which ones should I be looking out for in Pokémon Go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of now (18th Dec 2016), there are 8 Gen 2 Pokémon available in the game:

- **Cleffa**, **Igglybuff** - from 2 km eggs
- **Pichu**, **Togepi** - from 5 km eggs
- **Elekid**, **Magby**, **Smoochum** - from 10 km eggs
- **Togetic** - by evolving Togepi

Answer (score 8):

Most Pokemon from the first three generations are currently available in Pokemon Go. This includes all Pokemon with Pokedex numbers 1 through 384 as well as all existing Alolan variants of Kanto Pokemon, with a few exceptions.

The following Mythical Pokemon have never been available, there is a chance they will be future Special Research rewards or EX Raid Bosses:

- Jirachi
- Deoxys

The following Legendary Pokemon are or were only available as Raid Bosses or Field Research Breakthrough rewards for a limited time:

- Articuno
- Zapdos
- Moltres
- Mewtwo (EX)
- Raikou
- Entei
- Suicune
- Lugia
- Ho-Oh
- Regirock
- Regice
- Registeel
- Latias
- Latios
- Kyogre
- Groudon
- Rayquaza
- Nincada, Ninjask where reward for basic research in November 2018
- Shedinja

The following Pokemon are currently unavailable and it's unclear when they will be added:

- Smeargle (possibly for a 2019 Easter event)
- Clamperl, Huntail, Gorebyss

The following Pokemon are region-exclusive and only available in specific locations, some special events make them available in different locations for a limited time:

- Farfetch'd (East Asia)
- Kangaskhan (Australia)
- Mr. Mime (Europe)
- Tauros (North America)
- Heracross (South America)
- Corsola (a band around the globe in the tropical zone, only near coasts)
- Torkoal (South Asia)
- Relicanth (New Zealand and surrounding areas)
- Tropius (Africa)
- Parichisu (Northern Latitudes)

The following Pokemon are available in one half of the world, respectively, and appear to switch sides every once in a while. This means only one of each pair is available in any given region:

- Solrock vs. Lunatone
- Seviper vs. Zangoose
- Volbeat vs. Illumise

The Pokemon Unown is extremely rare, but has massively increased spawns in areas around special events. On these occasions, the letters corresponding to the event appear very frequently. For example, Unown S, A, F, R and I were spawning commonly during the various Safari Zone events in Europe in 2017.

There are also some Pokemon with substantial regional differences in spawn rate, but no extensive information is currently available. Swinub, for example, is very common in cold climate zones, but very rare in hot climate zones.

Comment: Ha: there's a Heracross defending the gym at South Station in Boston right now. Must be a world traveler around here. (There's been a Mr. Mime defending around here as well.)

Answer (score 6):

As of [November 27th 2017](https://pokemongolive.com/en/post/legendary-hooh), nearly all the Pokemon from the second generation have been added to the game, the only exceptions being [Celebi](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Celebi_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) and [Smeargle](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Smeargle_(Pok%C3%A9mon)). It doesn't mean that you can catch all of them from now on though, as most of the Legendaries have been added for a limited amount of time through the raid system. So [Raikou](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/raikou/), [Entei](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/entei/), [Suicune](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/suicune/), [Lugia](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/lugia/) and [Ho-Oh](https://rankedboost.com/pokemon-go/ho-oh/) can only be caught during some special events when they are reintroduced to the game for a limited time. The same applies to the legendaries of the first generation. [Mew](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mew_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) is also still missing.

As of [December 22nd 2017](https://pokemongolive.com/en/post/ver-update-120817), 75 Pokemon of the third generation have been introduced already, which current list can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zq08g.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdu7i.png).

Answer (score -4):

Pretty much any gen 2 starter Pokemon. I had early access and all I've seen are starters.

Togepi is the only non-starter Pokemon that I have seen